# How to search within a specific document

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

The use case I have is that I would like to use the azure search "hit" highlighting to check (and visulize) if a set of key words exists for a specific key id (e.g. my_id).

Example query:

/docs?api-version=2020-06-30&search="search term 1" OR "search term 2" OR "search term 3"

AND my_id = "some id"

(As opposed to searching across the entire database and getting multiple document hits).

But not matter what variation I can't seem to limit the search scope to just a specific document?

Any help or guidance would be much apreciated!

UPDATE 13-OCT-2020

The solution  was based on two issues:

1. Postman encoded = for the filter
2. The Guid had to be entered surrounded by single quotes

Thanks to @ramero-MSFT for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filters to limit the scope of documents to search in -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters

Make sure the "key" field is marked as filterable in your index.

Comment: Hi Ramero, thanks for your feedback. I'm still not getting the desired result when I use the filter e.g. appending the following filter to the search string:  $filter=my_id eq d4eee495-c541-466c-aedb-48588003d1c9 - the result still returns all matches and not just the document that matches my_id. I would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm the my_iq field is marked as "filterable" in the index definition?

Comment: Yes the id field is marked as fitlerable: https://snipboard.io/TXoJ9G.jpg - thanks in advance any further help!

Comment: Just to make sure, can you share your full search re quest payload? The $filter value shouldnt be within the search string itself, it should be its own query parameter. Also, the example online indicate adding single quotes around the value, so maybe try my_id eq 'd4eee495-c541-466c-aedb-48588003d1c9'

Comment: @ramereo-MSFT Thanks and yes here is the query string: /docs?api-version=2020-06-30&queryType=full&search="person connected with"&$count=true&$top=100&$skip=0&$filter=publication_id eq 'd4eee495-c541-466c-aedb-48588003d1c9'

Comment: I just realized I didnt get you tagged properly in my previous reply - any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @ramero-MSFT I was checking in to hear you had any further thoughts on the issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @martingp, the request you shared look good. If you don't mind, could you record a fiddler session while sending the request and share it with me? My email is my stackoverflow user name (minus the -MSFT) at microsoft.com